# Can a Jenkins image be used as base for installing WSO2 Identity Server?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I would like to try out the WSO2 Identity Server.  It has a number of prerequisites (Apache Maven, Ant) as described [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Installation+Prerequisites).  Since a [Bitnami Jenkins image](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/apps/jenkins/) satisfies these requirements (I think), can I just spin up one on Google Cloud and use it as a base for installing WSO2 IS?

If not, please suggest an alternative image that would be convenient for WSO2 IS requiring minimum amount of preparation in terms of additional installs.

The worst case is starting with a bare Ubuntu 14.04 image and going through the steps to install all the prerequisite packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Maven, Ant for installing and running the product. You need only JDK installed to run the product.

By default WSO2 Identity Server uses H2 database, but you can use any industry-standard RDBMS such as Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL, MS SQL, etc.

All WSO2 Carbon-based products are Java applications that can be run on any platform that is Oracle JDK 7/8 compliant. Also, we do not recommend or support OpenJDK

All WSO2 Carbon-based products are generally compatible with most common DBMSs. The embedded H2 database is suitable for development, testing, and some production environments. For most enterprise production environments, however, we recommend you use an industry-standard RDBMS such as Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL, MS SQL, etc. For more information, see Working with Databases. Additionally, we do not recommend the H2 database for use as a user store.

WSO2 Identity Server is shipped with a default embedded Apache DS. However, in a production environment, it is recommended to use an LDAP like OpenLDAP, due to scalability issues that exist with Apache DS.

Answer (score 1):

You only need a JDK as a mandatory requirement for running WSO2 IS. 
You can just use a bare Ubuntu instance with Java (Oracle JDK) and start WSO2 IS using the shell script.

You would need maven etc if you are to build the samples form source. Else, no need.